# Correct Academic Title, Necessity of Adding All Emails, Necessity of Adding Authors Photo in IEEE Transaction Journal?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, ieee

I should provide a concise biography of myself for IEEE transactions journal. We received the paper proof and this biography goes at the end of our accepted paper. At one point in my biography I should add my current position. So, I’ve written the following sentence. `“He is currently a lecturer in ABC University”`
ABC University is a small university that I am teaching some academic courses there. I am working there with my Master degree and teach the student who are purchasing Bachelor degree in Electrical engineering. I am not an associated, assistant or full professor. I am a part time instructor that is qualified to teach these students. Also, I don't have any constant commitment to the university as well. I fill out a contract form for each semester and get paid based on the hours that I teach at the university. So I would like to ask:

> what is my exact ranking title? A lecturer, instructor, adjunct
> lecturer, adjunct instructor or what?
>
> How much is it important to be precise for academic title in this
> biography?

My professor which is the corresponding author of this paper didn't add my email at the foot note of paper and only added his own email there. He was concern about exceeding 8 page limit of IEEE transactions papers in first submission of the manuscript. In the other stages where we received the revision of the paper he said we will add it after the acceptance stage.... so, right now we received the IEEE proof PDF of the paper and we are only asked to prepare a  Biography.So I would like to ask:

> Is it important to include all authors email in the paper? (I am the
> first name on the paper and he is the second, but he is the
> corresponding author)
>
> considering the fact that, we only received the PDF of the paper, How
> can we correct the foot note at this stage?

The IEEE editorial board didn't ask us about providing a photo beside our biography. Why is that? All publications of this kid of transactions have a photo beside authors biography. Also, in the 'authors guide' it is mentioned that a photo and biography is needed. on the other hand, my professor told me we only send them our short biography, because after their pedantic revision our paper became 13 pages and we should pay about 550$ fine. So, I would like to ask:

> Is it important to add our photo beside biography?
> Considering the fact that we didn't exceed 8 page limit of IEEE in the first
> submission of our manuscript, and the other 5 pages has been added to
> the paper based on the reviewers revision and editing of the editorial
> board, Do we still need to pay that fine? Also, My professor and I are
> Senior member and Student of IEEE organization, does that help us to
> get rid of paying the fine?

Your help is much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is my exact ranking title? A lecturer, instructor, adjunct
>   lecturer, adjunct instructor or what?
>
> How much is it important to be precise for academic title in this
>   biography?

If you are uncertain about your official title, talk to folks in your departmental office and/or the human resources (HR) people (or folks in the equivalent HR office at your institution). So long as you are making a good effort to state truthfully what your current title is, I wouldn't expect there to be any problems.

> Is it important to include all authors email in the paper? (I am the
>   first name on the paper and he is the second, but he is the
>   corresponding author)
>
> considering the fact that, we only received the PDF of the paper, How
>   can we correct the foot note at this stage?

I have seen folks list email addresses for all authors, just the email address of the corresponding author, or somewhere in between. It's up to you: you have every right to have your email address shown on the first-page footnote if you want it there. To make any additions to the footnote (or your biography, or anything else as I mentioned in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24295/what-to-do-when-you-discover-computational-errors-and-mistakes-in-your-accepted/24306#24306)), contact the senior editor assigned to your manuscript. If you don't know who the senior editor is, the corresponding author of your paper does: contact your corresponding author and ask them to supply you with this information.

> Is it important to add our photo beside biography? Considering the
>   fact that we didn't exceed 8 page limit of IEEE in the first
>   submission of our manuscript, and the other 5 pages has been added to
>   the paper based on the reviewers revision and editing of the editorial
>   board, Do we still need to pay that fine? Also, My professor and I are
>   Senior member and Student of IEEE organization, does that help us to
>   get rid of paying the fine?

Again, it's up to you: some authors have bios with pictures, some do not (some people choose not to even include a bio!). To me, the IEEE Transactions have very clear policies on the charges authors pay for going over a certain page limit: everyone pays these regardless of whether they are members of the IEEE or not.

Finally, don't let your corresponding author "bully" you into omitting your bio/photo just to save on publishing costs. As a corresponding author, even though I don't care if my bio has to be shortened to fit some page-count restriction, I always make sure to save room for co-author bios/photos and find other ways to trim the paper down without sacrificing the overall quality of the paper. The way I see it, if a co-author wants to include a bio/photo to, for example, advertise themselves to the journal's target audience, then they should be given the opportunity to do so.

Comment: For the last paragraph: perhaps the issue is that including longer bios with photos would add another page to the paper, resulting in a higher charge?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I have clarified a bit in the last paragraph.